# Query another app from cloud code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have multiple apps hosted on parse.com, each with their own cloudcode. Since the cloudcode is deployed using the Parse command line tool, I don't need to set up the requests with any App keys. Is it possible to query, post, or otherwise from one app's cloudcode to the other app's database?

As an example, let's say that whenever an object is created in one app, I would like it to also be created in the other. Or maybe I would like to check the other app's _User class for a matching username and other identifying info and perform some logic.

Comment: why do you have multiple apps ? you'd need to write the code and embed all the keys in each set of cloud code...

Comment: I have multiple products in a product line that have their own iOS app, backend database, and business logic. I would like to be able to possibly link accounts across the apps, or have data received in one app shared with another. It is more convenient for me for each product to have its own Parse app rather than share and have all subclasses in one app. How would I go about embedding the keys in cloud code?

Comment: as string literals...

Comment: could you provide an example of how to indicate that I do not want to use the Parse app whose cloud code has been called, but rather a different app? In my experience with cloud code any query you create will use the associated Parse app. So I am struggling to find the one or two lines that will allow me to query elsewhere...

Comment: it would be a call from cloud code in 1 app to cloud code in the other, simple REST call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a cloud function, you can invoke it with an http post.  Use `Cloud.httpRequest` to do that from any app to any other app.  The app identity is established with the `X-Parse-Application-Id` header.

Comment: Thank you! Cloud.httpRequest was exactly what I was missing. Here's what I ended up doing: `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  type: 'GET',
  headers: {
  'X-Parse-Application-Id':'',
  'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':''},
  url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/AthleteProfile?where={"email":"'+request.object.get("email")+'"}',
  data: {limit:1},
  contentType: 'application/json',
   }).then(function(httpResponse) {
     var profile = httpResponse.results;
   },function(httpResponse) {
     // error
     console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
   });`